# Regex pattern for keyword with ( bracket

Tags: powershell

Following keyword need to be searched on document using PowerShell:

```
$keyword = "The Parent shall pay to the Security Agent ("
Get-Content $SourceFileName | Select-String -Pattern $keyword
```

$keyword has "(" opening bracket - how to mention this using regex in powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the opening bracket with a backslash `\`

```
$keyword = "The Parent shall pay to the Security Agent \("
```

Answer (score 2):

By default `Select-String` does regular expression matches. In a regular expression parentheses have a special meaning: they group subexpressions and assertions. For matching a literal parenthesis in a regular expression it must be escaped with a backslash.

Generally speaking, if you want `Select-String` to match a pattern as a literal string either use the `-SimpleMatch` parameter:

```
Get-Content $SourceFileName | Select-String -Pattern $keyword -SimpleMatch
```

or escape the pattern:

```
Get-Content $SourceFileName | Select-String -Pattern ([regex]::Escape($keyword))
```